# White space appearing on tablet or browser resize

Tags: html, css

On my current project I am in the process of building tablet and mobile versions of the site and am testing it within the browser at the different sizes, though I am coming across a problem when resizing the browser.

The current version of the site can be found at: http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/

Please test this : http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/|768|1024

Basically whenever I resize the browser to check how it will look on the tablet for example, white space is rendered to the right and the x scrollbar appears, even though the width of the containing element has not been exceeded.

I can pretty much solve the issue by adding overflow: hidden but this disables x scrolling completely, which I don't want.

I have tested this across all major browsers, all respond the same, so it must be to do with the CSS, what exactly I'm not too sure, but it's probably something very simple that I've managed to miss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using? I see no problems (Mac OSX with Chrome 28).

Comment: Please check here : http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/|768|1024

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change `.pad-20 {padding:20px}` to `.pad-20 {padding:20px 0}` and of course remove the `overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden` from the `body`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your suggestion didn't fix the issue. Please have a look here : http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/|768|1024

Comment: You didn't apply my fix on the test site. When I do it (in the browser using Chrome dev tools) it fixes the problem for me. You will run into other problems, most notably caused by the `.wrapper` being set to `width: 1000px`. When you set that to `width: auto` it will be better. But still, more work is needed to let all blocks flow nicely but the white space problem on the right side is gone.

Comment: thanks, I have applied your fix you can view it at. It took worst at desktop browsers : http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/index1.html but it took good at mobile browsers : http://responsivetest.net/#u=http://demo1.zenithtechnosol.net/simlim/html/index1.html|768|1024

Comment: Sure, there are more issues with the layout of your site but that's due to other problems in your CSS (e.g. `float`ing elements and fixed `width`s). Making your website responsive is a lot of work and generally requires a design and HTML/CSS structure that was from the ground up designed and built to be responsive. It's sometimes (mostly?) easier to start with the mobile site and work your way up in screen resolution.